# Framer Motion "repeatType" prop causing Type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, framer-motion

I'm getting the following error appear on my `variants` prop when I include the `repeatType` property in my transition:

> index.d.ts(2779, 5): The expected type comes from property 'variants' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributesWithoutMotionProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement> & MotionProps & RefAttributes<...>'

Here's a snippet from the component:

```
const ScrollPrompt = () => {

    const variant = {
        animate: {
            y: [0, 42],
            opacity: [0, 1],
            scale: [0.8, 1],
            transition: {
                duration: 1,
                repeat: Infinity,
                ease: "easeInOut",
                repeatType: "mirror",
            },
        },
    };
    
    return (
        <Container>
            <motion.div variants={variant} animate="animate" />
        </Container>
    );
};
```

So far I've discovered:

1. The error persists if I roll back to a previous version of Framer Motion
2. The error disappears if I remove `repeatType`

Here's a list of my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "eslint": "8.33.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "framer-motion": "9.0.0",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
```

This is a Next js project with TypeScript, my previous project was set up the same way and I used the `repeatType` property without any problems, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Add the type in const declaration :Variants - plural, as this is an object that can contain more than one - typescript is geting confused here with auto assignment I think. Like so:

```js
const motionVariants: Variants = {
  animate: {
    scale: [0.75, 1.3, 1.3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    scaleX: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.25, 0.75, 1],
    scaleY: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.75, 1.25, 1],
    rotate: [0, 0, 270, 270, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    borderRadius: ["20%", "10%", "50%", "50%", "20%", "0%", "0%", "20%"],
    transition: { duration: 8, repeat: Infinity, repeatType: "mirror" },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the value as

`repeatType: "mirror" as const,`